# How to mange customer custom address attribute based on website in order detail page customer address edit?

Tags: magento2.3.3, magento-2-commerce, magento-ee, address-attribute, customer-address-attribute

FOR: Magento 2.3.3 enterprise edition.
How can I use the Customer custom attribute in adminhtml customer address?

Scenario: we have two websites having different customer custom address attributes e.g street or Pincode just an example. street should not show in website A but in website, B.and Pincode should show in website B. (it's working fine for checkout page customer registration and customer address) How can also manage these in Magento backend adminhtml customer address...

problem: adminhtml showing both(website A, B) custom fields in customer address in order detail page.

Comment: The only way i see is to extends the core template to check by yourself what store view you are under in order to print or not the data. Or may be you can trick it with some javascript too checking the store view and hiding / showing the fields.

Comment: @Claims can we manage fields as frontend for backend also ?? like select option in  field : form to use in (adminhtml_customer_address_edit) ?

At first, I thought same. override core template and add condition to check website wise from order detail.

Comment: As long as you define the layout `module/view/adminhtml/layout/your_page.xml` then I would say you can do whatever you want. Basically that layout you are looking for might already exist in magento core. So you might just be able to extend the template without even defining the layout.